# CSS selector combine with And operation '&&'

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I am trying to use querySelectorAll() to get each 'td' element that have align attribute && is child of 'tr'

this works :

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr>td');
```

and this works :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[align]');
```

but how to combine them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: There's no point whatsoever to `tr>` in front of `td`: [The **only** valid parent element for a `td` is a `tr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). So I've left that off below.

---

That depends on what you want to do.

1. If you only want `td` elements with an `align` attribute:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll("td[align]")
   ```
2. Or only `td` elements that are children of `tr` elements that have an `align` attribute

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll("tr[align]>td")
   ```
3. Or only elements with an `align` attribute that are *children* of `td` elements:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll("td[align]")
   ```
4. Or only elements with an `align` attribute that are *descendants* (not necessarily direct children) of `td` elements:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll("td [align]")
   ```

...and so on; [full details in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

---

Re your comment below:

> It works, but is there a way to not select the first td from each tr ?

There's nothing about that in your question.

You *could* use `td:not(:nth-child(0))` which means "a `td` that is not the first child of its parent" **provided** that you never have a `script` element as the first child of a `tr` (which is valid, but an odd thing to do). With that proviso, it works, because only `td` and `script` are valid children for `tr`.

Or you could just punt and select all the relevant `td`s and then:

```
var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector("whatever"), 1);
```

...which will give you an array skipping the first entry in the list returned by `querySelectorAll`.

---

Re your further comment:

> `tr[style]>td[align]:not(:nth-child(0))` returned 550 node lists which is the same as `tr[style]>td[align]`

Right. Again, `:nth-child` looks to see what child it is, **not** where it falls in the list chosen by the previous selector.

If you want to skip the first `td` in **each** row, and you want to ignore `tr` that don't have a `style` attribute, it's more complicated:

```
var result = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("tr[style]"),
    function(list, row) {
        list.push.call(
            list,
            Array.prototype.slice.call(row.querySelectorAll("tr[align]"), 1)
        );
        return list;
    },
    []
);
```

Comment: The `tr>td` part is certainly needed in some cases. There could be a nested table (don't do this!) and you only want to affect the first level. Unlikely though.

Comment: It works, but is there a way to not select the first td from each tr ?

Comment: @aaronburrows: `tr>td` applies within nested tables as well. You only need the `tr>` part if there's **more** to the selector.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right. I haven't finished my coffee yet this morning. :)

Comment: @victory: I didn't see anything about "first" elements in your question. Yes, you can use `td:not(:nth-child(0))` to avoid the first `td` element in a row, **provided** you don't have any `script` elements in the row, because `td:not(:nth-child(0))` means "the `td` element that is not also the 0th child of its parent" and `tr` elements can contain `td`s *or* `script` elements, so in a bizarre setup, you could have a `script` as the 0th child instead of a `td`.

Comment: @victory: Just use `tr>td[align]:not(:first-child)`.

Comment: `tr[style]>td[align]:nth-child(0)` doesn't work yet `tr[style]>td[align]` works and returns 550 node lists.

How to fix it ?

Comment: @victory: Right, because `td[align]:nth-child(0)` means "a `td` that has an `align` attribute and is also the first child of its parent." It does **not** mean "the first `td` with an `align` attribute within its parent." CSS doesn't have that (yet). See the note I added to the end of my answer with a pragmatic way to handle that. Again, though: Please make sure questions are complete. There's nothing about skipping the first in your question.

Comment: @aaronburrows: `td>td[align]:not(:first-child)` means "a `td` that has an `align` attribute that is also not the first child" it does **not** mean "all but the first `td` with an `align` attribute in its parent". More coffee required, I think. :-)

Comment: `tr[style]>td[align]:not(:nth-child(0))` returned 550 node lists which is the same as `tr[style]>td[align]`

Comment: I am already using `return Array.prototype.map.call(tds, function(t) { return t.textContent; });` will it work if i put your line of code then above mine and change var tds to var list ?

Comment: @victory: I've updated the end of the answer to try to help further. Have to get back to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Combine them like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr>td[align]');
```

More info: [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Note: `<td>` is only permitted as a child of `<tr>` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine selectors the same way as in CSS, like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr>td[align]');
```

If you haven't nested tables, it's the as `document.querySelectorAll('td[align]');`.